# Mac Word 2011 Forms Assistance

Tags: mac, microsoft-word

I have scanned a pre-printed form, and I started a new Mac Word document using the form as the header.  I now want to use the form controls and create boxes and checkmarks for the user to enter the data needed.  I've turned on the Developer tab, but the form controls are grayed out.  How to I make them available.  Thanks for any suggestion you can provide.  Jim H

Comment: Just a guess, but if you still have your scanned image selected, you probably won't be able to create form fields. If you click in the document body, the controls may be enabled.